# Close a Tab Item and a remove a list item at the same index

Tags: c#, tabs, winui-3

I have this code:

```csharp
private void TabView_TabCloseRequested(TabView sender, TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs args) {
    if(!sender.TabItems.Remove(args.Tab)) {
        throw new Exception("Couldn't remove tab.");
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(args.Tab.TabIndex);

    int index = sender.TabItems.IndexOf(args.Tab.TabIndex);
    sender.TabItems.Remove(args.Tab);

    Debug.WriteLine(index);

    Variables.textViews.RemoveAt(index);

    Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\nDeleted list:");
    foreach (var item in Variables.textViews)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

What it's trying to do is when my `TabView` receives a close request, it removes the tab at the right index and (this is the part I'm having trouble with) removes the item at the same index from a list of `RichEditBox`s I have. The problem is that `args.Tab.TabIndex` is apparently 2147483647, and so sender.TabItems.IndexOf() returns -1.

How would I get the correct index of the tab needing to be removed and remove the item at that index from my list?

> P.S. Ignore the calls to `Debug.WriteLine(...)` and the `foreach` loop. They're just for debugging purposes.

Comment: You first remove the tab, then you look for the index of the index in the `TabView`, then you remove the tab _again_, and then you remove an item from a `List`.  What happens if you try to find the index of the tab _before_ you remove it? (And I would think you should use `.IndexOf(tab)` instead of `IndexOf(index)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TabIndex` property is not the index for TabItems. It is a value that determines the order in which elements receive focus when the user navigates through controls using the Tab key. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.tabindex?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3

You just need to use **args.Tab** for the `IndexOf` method.

Please try the following code instead:

```
var index = sender.TabItems.IndexOf(args.Tab);
```

Comment: And of course, getting that index should be done _before_ removing it from the `TabItems` collection, as the index will be -1 after that.